# how do I get prototype to work of a constructor function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
 var StartCountdown = function () {

  //grab value from the input text field
  var minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value;

  //check if the value passed is a number
  if (isNaN(minutes)) {
     timeDisplay.innerHTML = "Enter a numeric value";
     return;
  };

  //this variable will decrement
  secondsRemaining = minutes * 60;

  //the ticking function and the milisecond (1)
  // calls the method repeatedly
  intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000);

  //hide the input field once we have the numeric value
  // document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display = "none";

     StartCountdown.closeInputField;

  };

  StartCountdown.prototype = {

       closeInputField: function() {
               document.getElementById("inputArea").style.display = "none";
       }
  }
```

I would like to create prototype function of the `StartCountdown` Constructor function in order to learn how this is done correctly.

Here is the full version without prototype
http://jsfiddle.net/2nXbN/2/

Comment: Define the prototype after the constructor function is defined, not within it.

Comment: @PaulS. I thought the same thing because the brackets seem a bit off but the prototype is not in the constructor.

Comment: If you're using variables you'd like to access later you should specify them with `this.minutes` not with 'var minutes' or they wont be available as soon as you've created an instance. An introduction to using constructor functions and prototype can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
StartCountdown.closeInputField;
```

You'll want to call the function with

```
this.closeInputField();
```

**Note:** Make sure you use `()` to call a function. Without them, you're just referencing the function, not calling it.

---

You also don't have to create the prototype that way.

After creating the function, you can simply attach to the existing prototype.

```
var StartCountDown = function() {
  // ...
};

StartCountDown.prototype.closeInputField = function() {
  // ...
};
```

---

After looking taking a look at your fiddle, I see a couple other areas for improvement as well. These are just some ideas for you to use as you'd like.

[Here's a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2nXbN/6/)

Timer

```
var Timer = function(elem) {
  this.seconds = 0;
  this.elem     = elem;
  this.initialize();
};

Timer.prototype.initialize = function() {
  this.timer = document.createElement("span");
  this.timer.innerHTML = "0:00";

  this.input = document.createElement("input");

  this.button = document.createElement("button");
  this.button.innerHTML = "Submit";
  this.button.addEventListener("click", this.startTimer.bind(this));

  this.elem.appendChild(this.timer);
  this.elem.appendChild(this.input);
  this.elem.appendChild(this.button);
};

Timer.prototype.startTimer = function(event) {
  this.removeInput();
  this.seconds = parseInt(this.input.value) * 60;
  this.interval = window.setInterval(this.countDown.bind(this), 1000);
  event.preventDefault();
};

Timer.prototype.stopTimer = function() {
  this.updateTimer("Done!");
  window.clearInterval(this.interval);
};

Timer.prototype.updateTimer = function(text) {
  this.timer.innerHTML = text;
};

Timer.prototype.countDown = function() {
  if (this.seconds === 0) {
    return this.stopTimer();
  }

  this.updateTimer(this.timeRemaining(this.seconds));
  this.seconds--;
};

Timer.prototype.timeRemaining = function(seconds) {
  var minutes   = Math.floor(seconds/60),
      seconds   = seconds % 60,
      separator = seconds % 2 === 0 ? ":" : " ";

  if (seconds.toString().length < 2) {
    seconds = [0, 0, seconds].slice(-2).join("");
  }

  return minutes + separator + seconds;
};

Timer.prototype.removeInput = function() {
  this.input.remove();
  this.button.remove();
};
```

Usage

Find a DOM element (`elem`) you want to behave like a timer and call `new Timer(elem)`

```
var timer = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
new Timer(timer);
```

Multiple timers

```
var timers = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i=0, len=timers.length; i<len; i++) {
  new Timer(timers[i]);
}
```